# How to deploy new version of Ruby on Rails app on Elastic Beanstalk without resetting database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Ruby on Rails app deployed on elastic beanstalk and the first time I performed 'upload and deploy' in the eb console it reset everything in my database. Is this standard and does anyone know a way around it? If not, then I can ask another question with more details about why this might have happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrated RDS Instances are not intended for production use, [per the AWS documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html)

> For a production environment, you can launch a database instance outside of your environment and configure your application to connect to it outside of the functionality provided by Elastic Beanstalk. Using a database instance that is external to your environment requires additional security group and connection string configuration. However, it also lets you connect to the database from multiple environments, use database types not supported with integrated databases, perform blue/green deployments, and tear down your environment without affecting the database instance.

As the documentation advises, you should create your RDS instance detached from Elastic Beanstalk.